# std::min/max type deduction different on linux and windows

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, gcc, stl

In the following code, the template type deduction for std::min/max seems to be weird and I'd like to know why and how to properly fix it.

The following works on Windows VS2013, and gives a compile-error on GCC-4.8: (see below for the error)

```
int minX = max(min(floor(v1[0]), min(floor(v2[0]), floor(v3[0]))), 0.0f);
```

And this compiles on GCC-4.8 but gives a compile-error on VS2013: (see below for the error)

```
int minX = max(min(floor(v1[0]), min(floor(v2[0]), floor(v3[0]))), 0.0);
```

`v[1-3]` are a `cv::Vec3f v1, v2, v3;`

from OpenCV, a cv::Vec3f is a `Vec<float, 3>` and `Vec`'s operator[] is

```
const _Tp& operator [](int i) const;
_Tp& operator[](int i);
```

The min/max/floor/ceil are from the std:: namespace (i.e. `using std::min` etc. at the top of the code).

So when I write

```
int minX = max(min(floor(v1[0]), min(floor(v2[0]), floor(v3[0]))), 0.0f);
```

the types should be

```
max(min(float, min(float, float), float);
```

So why does GCC bail out here?

Error on VS2013:

```
error C2782: 'const _Ty &std::max(const _Ty &,const _Ty &)' : template parameter '_Ty' is ambiguous
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\algorithm(4086) : see declaration of 'std::max'
          could be 'double' or 'float'
```

Error on GCC-4.8:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'max(const double&, float)'
```

**Answer:**

GCC wasn't using std::floor but floor from the global namespace (drawn in by cmath). If I add `using std::floor`, all the code works as expected! Nasty double floor(...) function in the global namespace!

Comment: MSVC is correct: when you call `max(float, double)`, the template parameter cannot be resolved unambiguously. However, I [cannot reproduce](http://ideone.com/o7OK4c) GCC error you claim you are seeing.

Comment: Could you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can simply copy and paste and have it exhibit your problem? Preferably without the OpenCV dependency.

Comment: See here http://goo.gl/sxzvnC, play with the `using std::floor`. This is the answer :-) I'll update my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is not a typo then in this statement

```
int minX = max(min(floor(v1[0]), min(floor(v2[0]), floor(v3[0]))), 0.0);
```

integer literal `9.9` has type `double` while other operands have type float. So the compiler can not decide whether to use template argument `float` or `double`

The error message says clear that for function

```
'const _Ty &std::max(const _Ty &,const _Ty &)'
```

there `could be 'double' or 'float'`

That is the funcrion call looks as

```
std::max( float_value, double_value );
```

You could explicitly specify the template argument as for example

```
std::max<double>( float_value, double_value );
```

or

```
std::max<float>( float_value, double_value );
```

As for GCC then it places the standard C function `floor` that has return type `double` in the global namespace..

```
double floor(double x);
```

So the operands after applying this function are converted to the type double.  But it seems that MS VC++ does not places this function in the global namespace or the global namespace in MS VC++ has overloaded functions with the same name.

So the problem is relative to what function(s) `floor` each compiler places in the global namespace.

I think that if you used qualified name `std::floor`  then GCC would also issue an error.

So in your code MS VC++ uses function

```
float floor(float x);
```

and as the result issues the error while GCC uses function

```
double floor(double x);
```

and all operands of function `std::max` have type `double` and the code is compiled successfully.:)

Comment: Yes, I think we can all agree on the fact that MSVC is correct here. However, why does GCC fail when you put "0.0f".

Comment: @Ela782  You should check whether you indeed use the algorithm when the code is compiled using GCC.

Comment: "the algorithm"? Do you mean the min/max/floor from <algorithm>? In that case yes, what else should GCC use? (I use the STL wherever possible, not my own implementations)

Comment: @@Ela782 I described the reason of the different behaviours of the compilers.

Comment: You nailed it in the second part of your answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So the thing that is probably confusing you is a terrible hack in the Windows platform headers that has been there for ages:

From deep inside "ntdef.h"

```
#ifndef NOMINMAX

#ifndef min
#define min(a,b) (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#endif

#ifndef max
#define max(a,b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#endif

#endif  // NOMINMAX
```

That means in all likelihood, your Windows build is probably using the #define macro and not `<algorithm>`'s min/max as you think it is.

If you use `std::min` or `std::max` explicitly, this will avoid the macro expansion, as would `max<T>` and `min<T>`. Personally I make a point of doing `#define NOMINMAX` before including `<windows.h>` or headers that are going to include that header in all my projects so I get "standard" behavior. For example, a this is the Precompiled Header I use in [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929):

```
#if !defined(WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN)
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

#if !defined(NOMINMAX)
#define NOMINMAX
#endif

#include <d3d11_1.h>

#include <DirectXMath.h>

#include <algorithm>
...
```

See KB [143208](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/143208/en-us)

Of course, this assumes that the module in question has pulled `<windows.h>` in somehow...

Comment: Yes I knew about the macros and about NOMINMAX. It's handy if you need to include windows.h. I however did not include windows.h as the code is completely platform independent. Also I think MSVC behaves as it should, while GCC's behaviour is weird.

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember in the math implementation in GCC-4.8 the floor function returns `double`. That's the problem. Try to explicitly cast onto float or try to use your own`floor`.

Comment: That depends on the type deduction.

Comment: Yes but I pass it a float, so it should return a float. Anyway with the help from the answers I figured it out now, I'll update my post!