# When i try to compile a program i got a bunch of errors like :'std::max': no matching overloaded function found

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

When i try to compile a program i got a bunch of errors like :

`'std::max': no matching overloaded function found`

```
 'const _Ty &std::max(const _Ty &,const _Ty &,_Pr) noexcept(<expr>)': expects 3 arguments - 2 provided


 C2782: 'const _Ty &std::max(const _Ty &,const _Ty &) noexcept(<expr>)': template parameter '_Ty' is ambiguous


  C2784: 'const _Ty &std::max(const _Ty &,const _Ty &) noexcept(<expr>)': could not deduce template argument for 'const _Ty &' from 'int'
```

Here is the code that cause most problems :

```
 template <typename TVar>
    void CopyVar( void*& pTarget, const void*& pSource, int nAlign = 4 )
    {
        *((TVar*) pTarget) = *((TVar*) pSource);
        ((BYTE*&) pTarget) += max( sizeof(TVar), nAlign );
        ((BYTE*&) pSource) += max( sizeof(TVar), nAlign );
    }
```

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::min/max type deduction different on linux and windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086999/stdmin-max-type-deduction-different-on-linux-and-windows) or [Why can't compiler determine template of std::max with literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27004024/580083).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't compiler determine template of std::max with literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27004024/why-cant-compiler-determine-template-of-stdmax-with-literal)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) operator returns a value of type [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t), which is an *unsigned* integer type.

Your call to [`std::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) mixes two different types (the unsigned `size_t` and the signed `int`), and [`std::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) requires both arguments to be of the same type.

As mentioned in a comment, a suitable solution is to make the `nAlign` variable the same type, i.e. a `size_t`. Alignment can never be negative, and is also a kind of a size. It also ensures that the types are the same size (`size_t` can be a 64-bit type, while `unsigned int` usually is 32 bits).

If changing the type of `nAlign` is not possible, then you should cast the result of `sizeof` to `int` (it's safer, since someone could pass a negative value for `nAlign` which will have bad consequences if casted to an unsigned type).

Comment: Or explicitly call `std::max<std::size_t>`.